# Simple Stochastic Epidemic Model

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

While going through a book for the topic **Simple Stochastic Model**, it starts off with defining the notations as:

Let $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ denote the number of susceptible and infectives respectively at time $t$.

Let $\beta$ be the infection rate such that the number of infections during an infinitesimal interval of time $(t, \delta t)$ is:
$$\beta X(t) Y(t) \delta t$$ subject to $X(0) + Y(0) = n+1$

Also, it is assumed that $X(0) = n$ and $Y(0) = 1$.

Now, in the book it is stated that:

> $$p_r(t) = \mathbb{P}[X(t) = r | X(0) = n; Y(0) = 1]$$

and goes on to state that:

> Putting $\tau = \beta t \implies p_r(\tau) = \beta p_r(t)$

I am not able to understand how is $p_r(\tau) = \beta p_r(t)$? The book is also silent about any explanation for it. Could someone please explain why the equality should hold?

Thanks in advance!

Here is a snapshot of the portion of the book that I am talking about:

[image]